# Convert PHP script to be compatible with magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

```
PHP script used:
$product=Mage::getModel('core/store');
$product->load($order->getStoreId());
$value=$product->getWebsiteId(); 
return $value;
if (strpos($value, '1') !== false) {
  return "34501";
} 
else if (strpos($value, '3') !== false) {
  return "34502";
}
else if (strpos($value, '2') !== false) {
  return "34503";
} 

Example of expected result:
34501
```

I tried many times but I did't found anything can you help me out this is my first task

Comment: You have a return statement before your `if` block. Code after a `return` will not be executed. You should move it after your conditional blocks. So either one of the three values is returned or as a default `$value`will be returned.

Comment: @Hiren If you provide more information that what do you want to achieve, someone may help you. Your give code does not provide clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to optimize your code. Please check below if it could be helpful for you. And also, check the conditions you have used; it might be the case the product could not be found with the passing id you have used. Could you handle this try-and-catch statement?

Better to use a switch case statement.

```
$product=Mage::getModel('core/store');
$product->load($order->getStoreId());
$value=$product->getWebsiteId();

try {
  if (strpos($value, '1') !== false) {
    return "34501";
  } 
  else if (strpos($value, '3') !== false) {
    return "34502";
  }
  else if (strpos($value, '2') !== false) {
    return "34503";
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception('Value Not Found');
  }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

OR

```
$product=Mage::getModel('core/store');
$product->load($order->getStoreId());
$value=$product->getWebsiteId(); 

if (strpos($value, '1') !== false) {
  return "34501";
} 
else if (strpos($value, '3') !== false) {
  return "34502";
}
else if (strpos($value, '2') !== false) {
  return "34503";
} 
else {
  return 'Value not found';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have done but it's showing same error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/html/Nov/salecto-2.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Nov/salecto-2.php on line 2

Comment: Hi @Hiren, you need to write the script within the Magento main root directory otherwise, the Mage class won't work outside the Magento directory.

Also, please, initialize the Mage class as:

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();